# Codeigniter User Change Password

Tags: php, codeigniter, hash, password-encryption

Hello I am trying to create a user change password feature for the user control panel, and I have found something here tried to edit but I have some problems.

Here is the controller part

```
public function ucp_change_pass() {

    $data2['title'] = "Change Password";  
    $data = new stdClass();
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('old_password', 'Old Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('new_password', 'New Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('new_password_confirm', 'Old Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|matches[new_password]');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === false) {
     $this->load->view('header', $data2);
    $this->load->view('ucp/ucp_menu');
    $this->load->view('ucp/ucp_change_pass', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer');


        } else {    
    $old_password = $this->input->post('old_password');
    $new_password_confirm = $this->input->post('new_password_confirm');
    $query = $this->Home_model->checkOldPass($old_password);
    if($query){
    $query = $this->Home_model->saveNewPass($new_password_confirm);
    if($query){
      redirect('./ucp_change_pass_success');
    }else{
      redirect('./ucp_change_pass');
    }
  }

 }

 }
```

Here is the model part

```
public function checkOldPass($old_password){
$this->db->where('username', $this->session->userdata('username'));
$query = $this->db->get('users');
$row    = $query->row();
echo "Old Password : ".$this->hash_password($old_password)."<br>";
echo "From DB : ".$row->password."<br>";
die;

if($query->num_rows > 0){
  $row = $query->row();
  if($old_password == $row->password){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
   }
 }
```

}

```
public function saveNewPass($new_password_confirm){
$array = array(
        'password'=>$this->hash_password($new_password_confirm)
        );
$this->db->where('username', $this->session->userdata('username'));
$query = $this->db->update('users');
if($query){
  return true;
}else{
  return false;
}
}
```

and this is the view

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) != TRUE) {
echo redirect('/login');
} 
?>
```

```
<div class="col-md-9">
<div class="list-group">
<div class="list-group-item  ucp-nav-bar">User Control Panel</div>
<div class="list-group-item">
```

```
            <?= form_open() ?>



            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Old Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="old_password" name="old_password" placeholder="Enter your current password">

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">New Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="new_password" name="new_password" placeholder="Enter a new password">

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message">New Password Confrim</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="new_password_confirm" name="new_password_confirm" placeholder="Re-enter the new password for confirmation">

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Change      Password">
            </div>
        </form>
```

The problem I am having is that when I submit the input the old password encrypted with hash_password is not the same as the one in the database. 
The password in the database was encrypted with hash_password.

this is the function for hash_password in the model

Answer (score 0):

You need to decrypt the the $old_password in your controller. Change your else part of controller like this.

```
 $old_password = $this->input->post('old_password');
 $encrypted_old_password=password_hash($old_password) 
$new_password_confirm = $this->input->post('new_password_confirm');
$query = $this->Home_model->checkOldPass($encrypted_old_password);
```

You need to encrypt old password and then pass it to model.

Comment: the old password encription is done in the model. take a look here echo "Old Password : ".$this->hash_password($old_password)."<br>"; /////// also the hash_password function is this   private function hash_password($password) {
  
  return password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
  
 }